# Spring WebFlux Security OAuth 2.0 User Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

To give some context, I am currently migrating from standard Spring Security 5 (with `spring-boot-starter-web`) to `spring-webflux` - being used with the Spring Cloud Gateway as my API Gateway - which doesn't support `spring-boot-starter-web` dependencies.

I have got everything else working with Spring Reactor/Webflux - apart from my OAuth 2.0 User Service (that I had in the previous implementation). So I have copied the user service over - except I am now unable to reference that from the new Security Configuration.

Here's my new Security Configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

  private final OAuth2SuccessHandler oAuth2SuccessHandler;
  private final OAuth2FailureHandler oAuth2FailureHandler;
  private final OAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

  public SecurityConfig(OAuth2SuccessHandler oAuth2SuccessHandler, OAuth2FailureHandler oAuth2FailureHandler, OAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService) {
    this.oAuth2SuccessHandler = oAuth2SuccessHandler;
    this.oAuth2FailureHandler = oAuth2FailureHandler;
    this.customOAuth2UserService = customOAuth2UserService;
  }

  @Bean
  public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  public ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager(
          UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager =
        new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(userDetailsService);
    authenticationManager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    return authenticationManager;
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(
      ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
            .requestCache()
            .requestCache(NoOpServerRequestCache.getInstance())
            .and()
            .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/error",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/*/*.png",
                    "/*/*.gif",
                    "/*/*.svg",
                    "/*/*.jpg",
                    "/*/*.html",
                    "/*/*.css",
                    "/*/*.js")
            .permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/login/*", "/auth/*", "/oauth2/*")
            .permitAll()
            .anyExchange()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .authenticationSuccessHandler(oAuth2SuccessHandler)
            .authenticationFailureHandler(oAuth2FailureHandler)
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .oauth2Client();

    http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION);

    return http.build();
  }
}
```

Here's my OAuth 2.0 Custom User Service

```java
@Service
public class OAuth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

  private final UserDao userDao;

  public OAuth2UserService(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
  }

  @Override
  public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
    OAuth2User oAuth2User = super.loadUser(userRequest);

    OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo =
            OAuth2UserInfoFactory.getOAuth2UserInfo(
                    userRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(), oAuth2User.getAttributes());

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail())) {
      throw new OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingException("Email not found from any providers");
    }

    /* Find the user by email */
    User user = userDao.findUserByEmail(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail());

    try {
      if (user == null) throw new OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingException("You must sign up!");

      if (!user.getProvider().equals(AuthProvider.valueOf(userRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId()))) {
        throw new OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingException(
            "Woah! Looks like you're already signed up with your "
                + user.getProvider().getValue()
                + ". Please use your "
                + user.getProvider().getValue()
                + " account to login.");
      }

      user = registerNewUser(userRequest, oAuth2UserInfo);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return UserPrincipal.create(user, oAuth2User.getAttributes());
  }

  private User registerNewUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo) {
    User user = new User();

    user.setProvider(
            AuthProvider.valueOf(oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId()));
    user.setProviderId(oAuth2UserInfo.getId());
    user.setUsername(oAuth2UserInfo.getName());
    user.setEmail(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail());
    user.setProfilePicture(oAuth2UserInfo.getImageUrl());

    return userDao.save(user);
  }
}
```

the only difference between that and my old configuration was that I could use this

```java
http
    .userInfoEndpoint()
    .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
```

however, there is no option to use this with the **New Security Configuration** Options (that I am aware of) - so please answer if you know a way of pointing Spring Security to my Custom User Service.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your Service bean is for the regular OAuth flow. The actual one you want is the WebFlux one, which is `ReactiveOAuth2UserService`.

You can verify this for yourself by setting a breakpoint on the `ReactiveOAuth2UserService::loadUser` method and then authenticating normally.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment. Actually since then I've come up with another "hacky" way of doing it where you do the same stuff as you would with the userService inside the OAuth2SuccessHandlers implementations I had already. Will try it later and see if it works! 

Comment: I do trust that this works and it would definitely make more sense when I think about it, just gonna mark the answer as correct once I've actually implemented it.